# Compiling for arm64

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, arm64

I've got a major problem. When I'm trying to compile my iOS project for iPhone 4inch (64-bit), my compiler gives me the error: "Symbols not found for architecture x86_64". So I thought, no problem, let's compile this only 32 bit. I removed "arm64" from standard architectures in my Build Settings.

Now the compiler gives me another error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TKCoverflowCoverView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CoverFlowViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TKCoverflowView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CoverFlowViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone who knows how to solve this?

The project builds fine when compiling in a 32 bit simulator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: issue with TKCoverflowCoverView. Like including .m instead of .h accidentally.

Comment: the project just builds fine when compiling in 32 bit simulator.. :s

Comment: ah! sorry didn't notice that.. is TKCoverflowCoverView an external lib ?

Comment: If you are using an external library please run the following command on it and post the results in your question: `xcrun otool -L /path/to/library.a`.

Comment: fixed the issue. TapkuLibrary works as a "subproject". In that subproject I also changed the Build for settings. I didn't know that this was also possible. Thx for the help all